# Postgres multicorn undefined symbol oid_hash

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw, multicorn

I've built the multicorn extensions from source (downloaded 1.3.4 from pgxn website) but am unable to create extension. When I run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION multicorn;
```

The response I am getting is:

```
ERROR: could not load library "/usr/pgsql-10/lib/multicorn.so": /usr/pgsql-10/lib/multicorn.so: undefined symbol: oid_hash
SQL state: XX000
```

This is using Postgresql-10 on CentOS 7

Comment: I am also not able to install via "pgxn install" because there doesn't seem to be a way to use it through a proxy. Under some conditions I can also get "undefined symbol: copyObject"